# Is there any coarse language in season 1 of ST:TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

My copy of ST:TOS first season (Australian rating system) is rated M (ie 13 years or older) for 'Incidental coarse language'.  I have watched all of it and the worst I could pick was 'Dammit Jim!'.  Is there actually any language that is 'worse' than this (ie swearing etc.)?

Comment: Might the rating be for secondary materials? Interviews, commentaries, etc?

Comment: @Xantec I've watched those (although not as closely) and didn't notice any, but +1 for lateral thinking ;)

Comment: I don't have a specific quote from a particular episode, but it may refer to Dr. McCoy's species bias which he often spewed at Mr. Spock.

Comment: I cannot for the life of me remember anything above "Dammit".

Comment: Don't both McCoy and Kirk refer to Spock as a "bastard" on occasion? Of course, as a fellow Australian, it could just be that our ratings system is a joke. *Silence of the Lambs* and *Red Dragon* are rated MA, but the less violent *Hannibal* is rated R. Of course, *Hannibal* sucks while the other two are good films, but the rating system doesn't cover that.

Comment: If you could find out what episode they call Spock a 'bastard' and put that in an answer, that'd be great!  I agree that our rating system is ridiculous though - apparently the CareBears movie was rated PG!  Getting off topic I know ;)

Comment: Did a quick search of the transcripts site by putting mild curses along with site:http://www.chakoteya.net/startrek into google...I see that "City on the Edge of Forever" Kirk says "let's get the hell out of here" and in "A Piece of the Action" Krako says "How the hell'd I get here?", if that would qualify as "coarse language". And the only instance of "damn" that showed up was from "Journey to Babel" where Kirk said "I can't damn him for his loyalty", which doesn't really count as a swear. No examples of "bastard" showed up, though Spock was sometimes referred to as a "half-breed".

Comment: Also, in "The Savage Curtain" they had Abraham Lincoln say to Uhura, "What a charming negress. Oh, forgive me, my dear. I know in my time some used that term as a description of property." It's possible the term "negress" would have caught the attention the ratings board, even though it was being intentionally put in the mouth of a character from a different time who didn't mean it disrespectfully.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - thanks, but that's not part of Season 1, so it doesn't count (sorry)

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that you were only looking for first season episodes, which would rule out "A Piece of the Action" and "Journey to Babel" as well. I'll submit the thing about "City on the Edge of Forever" as an answer, though.

Comment: And Hypnosifl, in the context of "The Savage Curtain" I do not know how coarse the term 'negress' might me.  Uhura certainly didn't mind it and in the 1960's (when the program was produced) I believe the term 'negro' might still have been a widely accepted term for African Americans in the United States.

Comment: Perhaps the insults Kirk flings at Spock in [This Side of Paradise](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/This_Side_of_Paradise_(episode))?  They're insulting enough to anger a Vulcan, but if I'm remembering right what he said, it doesn't really apply to us humans - not sure the rating board would care.

Comment: @Izkata, there was no swearing in the insults Kirk hurled at Spock in "This Side of Paradise" as seen at http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/25.htm -- just stuff like "mutinous, disloyal, computerised, half-breed" and "a simpering, devil-eared freak whose father was a computer and his mother an encyclopedia" and "rotten like the rest of your subhuman race".

Comment: "Sub-human" might just push an Australian censor over the edge. It could be seen as describing the average Australian.

Comment: I recall Kirk saying something like "the evidence was damning", probably in "Court Martial".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After a quick search of the Australian ratings website, I've determined that the episodes themselves are free from "coarse language" but that the **additional materials** on the DVD (presumably some kind of commentary or interviews) are what's pushing it into the M category.

### Episodes

[image]

### Additional Materials

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I Did a quick search of the transcripts site chakoteya.net by putting mild curses along with "site:chakoteya.net/startrek" into a google search...I see that in "City on the Edge of Forever" Kirk says "let's get the hell out of here", maybe that would qualify as "coarse language". That was the only one I could find from the first season, there were no examples of "damn" or "damned" or "dammit" that turned up in first-season episodes (it appears McCoy never actually said "damn it Jim", just like Kirk never said "beam me up, Scotty").

Comment: It would be interesting to see if the other seasons of *TOS* have the same rating. It wouldn't be the first case in Australia of a series having a more restrictive rating than it should based on later seasons of the same show. *Raiders of the Lost Ark* receiving an M rating simply because *Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom* deserved that rating springs to mind.

Comment: @James Sheridan, I didn't really see anything worse language-wise in my search even though I was looking at transcripts from all three seasons, unless you count the thing about Abraham Lincoln using the antiquated term "negress". "Damn" seems never to have been used as a curse in any season, nor was "bastard" ever used.

Comment: I could have sworn McCoy called Spock a bastard at some point. Maybe I'm misremembering something from a book or script. It wouldn't be the first time I made that mistake.

Comment: "Dammit Jim, what the hell's the matter with you?  Other people have birthdays; why are we treating yours like a funeral?"  But that was in *The Wrath of Khan*.

Comment: @JamesSheridan: That happens in the 2009 movie.

Comment: @Stephan I could have sworn he said something like that in TOwtW (The One with the Whales).

Comment: @James Sheridan: I googled site:chakoteya.net/movies along with "trek" and "bastard", got just one example from the original Trek movies (they don't have transcripts of the J.J. Abrams movies): in Search for Spock, Kirk says "Klingon bastard! ...Klingon bastard! You've killed my son! ...You Klingon bastard!"

Comment: @Kyle Jones: good find, I wonder if that's where the "Dammit Jim" meme got started. Also, searching the transcripts site I see that although Kirk never said "beam me up, Scotty", and usually used "Mr. Scott" when asking Scotty for a beam-up, in the episode "The Savage Curtain" he did say "Scotty, beam us up fast." And in the animated series he said "beam us up, Scotty" in two episodes (The Lorelei Signal and The Infinite Vulcan), and in The Voyage Home said "Scotty, beam me up!"